# Woocommerce get custom values from woocommerce_checkout_create_order $order

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get custom field data from $order array. I saved it using **woocommerce_add_cart_item_data** and this code:

```
$cart_item_data["product_".$row->ID."_".$product_id] = wc_clean( $_POST["product_$row->ID"] );
```

Now I need to extract that data from $order variable (or some other way) to save this data to my custom table in database.
I'm using **woocommerce_checkout_create_order** filter. I can't find a way to access this data. I see it in $order array after var dumping it into error log.

```
"line_items": {
    "21": {
        "legacy_values": {

            \/ HERE IS THE DATA
            "product_25_163": "Szk\u0142o_900",
            "product_26_163": "Tak_120",


            "key": "9c05c43810f992ce265a47bf79071973",
            "product_id": 163,
            "variation_id": 0,
            "variation": [],
            "quantity": 1,
            "data_hash": "b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0",
            "line_tax_data": {
                "subtotal": [],
                "total": []
            },
            "line_subtotal": 13887,
            "line_subtotal_tax": 0,
            "line_total": 13887,
            "line_tax": 0,
            "data": {}
        },
        "legacy_cart_item_key": "9c05c43810f992ce265a47bf79071973"
    }
},
```

Is there a way to get these values and store it into my custom table?

Comment: Based on that output, it looks like it is part of the order metadata? Can you confirm that?

Comment: I used error_log($order); and this is part of what I got in debug.log

Comment: If you look in the database can you confirm that is part of the order metadata? If it is, I can show you an easy way to pull it and send it to your custom table.

Comment: I've changed some code and now I can see it saved in woocommerce_order_itemmeta. How can I get them in woocommerce_checkout_create_order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the woocommerce_new_order hook.

http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/

```
add_action("woocommerce_new_order", "somefunctionname");
function somefunctionname( $order_id ) {
    // get order details data...
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    // get what data you need and insert into new table

}
```

If you have questions on how to insert data please see - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#insert-row